# nakagami distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, logarithm, fisher-scoring, nakagami-distribution

How can i do the parameter's estimation with nakagami distribution with fisher scoring ? i've problem with derive the log likelihood for the variabel of m.(i attach the picture with screenshot file)
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: If this is not just a classroom exercise, then things can be made much simpler by noting that the maximum likelihood estimator for $\Omega$ is $\hat{\Omega}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2/n$.